# Triple Nested For Loop / Huffman Decoding of a String using a codebook cell array in MatLab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell, decode, huffman-code

Im confused here. coded_msg is a long string of 1s and 0s. Codewords is a cell array of codewords of varying lengths (i.e. codewords(1) = 10010, codewords(2) = 101, etc). What I am trying to do is to iterate to the next index of i and k, and strcmp, and then concatenate to the_codeword if its true, but iterate through j if its false. All in all I want a list of codewords, instead of a string of them all together. Help?

```
function [coded_msg, idx] = HuffmanDecode(coded_msg, codewords)

for i = 1:length(coded_msg) % iterate through coded_msg
    for j = 1:length(codewords) % iterate through codewords cell array
        j_codeword = cell2mat(codewords(j)) % take the jth cell and put in matrix
        for k = 1:length(j_codeword) % iterate through length of jth codeword
            if strcmp(coded_msg(i), j_codeword(k)) % is true
                the_codeword = [coded_msg(i)];
            else % is false
              end
          end
      end
  end
end
```